# Use the same environment variable to point to User's Home directory on both Mac and Windows in .net core

Tags: .net-core, environment-variables

I have a .netcore application which reads the log path from appSettings.json.
I want to provide the default path to be something like `%HOME%/MyApp/Logs/Log.json`.

My code reads and expands the environment variable using [Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables?view=netcore-3.1).

Now the problem is this works on Mac but on windows %HOME% is not expanded. Rather %userprofile% works on Windows.

My question is- can you suggest me some environemt variable that will work on both the platforms? As I said it reads from json, so there is not much option for me to check the platform it's running on.